# Use one list on multiple pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm building an application for Windows Phone, and I was wondering if it is possible (and how)  to create a list one page of your app and use it and its content on other pages of this app.

Comment: you mean list data or list control?

Comment: not enough information, share some code as well.

Comment: Please try things and ask here.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop a User Control and use it in multiple pages.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714088%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_SharingXAMLUIusingaUserControl

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM concept for this, keep your data common as Model and use it where ever you want.

If you want the UI too in common as said before use UserControl for listbox and use it wherever you want.

Thank you.